# How to Format a Pivoted Time Column into HH:MM

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have created a pivot table with one of the column as 'Triage Start Time', the actual format of Triage Start time is - 01-JAN-2000 23:22, which I need to Format it as 23:22. If I format this under select statement, it is giving an error. Please help me to understand where should I give the format or convert command for Time ?

```
select*
from
(
select
,PFRM.FORM_RESULT_VAL
,PFRM.FORM_FIELD
,CAST(PFRM.FORM_DT_TM AS DATE) AS 'Form_date'
,P.NATIONALITY
,P.GENDER
,P.DOB
,P.AGEYEARS
,E.ENCNTR_TYPE
,DATENAME(DW, CAST(A.APPOINTMENT_DT_TM AS DATE)) DayofWeek
-- CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, CAST(A.APPOINTMENT_DT_TM AS DATE)),'Weekday',
--'Weekday','Weekday','Weekday','Weekday','WEEKEND','WEEKEND') WorkDay

FROM [ODS_CCL].[dbo].[ODS_CCL_APPOINTMENTS] A (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN [ODS_CCL].[dbo].[ODS_CCL_PFORMS] PFRM (NOLOCK) ON E.ENCNTR_ID=PFRM.ENCNTR_ID AND FORM_SECTION='PHCC Nursing Triage'
where A.APPOINTMENT_TYPE='Nursing Tele Triage'
) as source_table
pivot 
(
max(FORM_RESULT_VAL)
for FORM_FIELD in 
(
[Triage Start Time]
,[Triage End Time]
,[Triage Category]
,[Chief Complaint]
)
) as pivot_table
where Form_date>='2020-12-27' and Form_date<='2021-01-02'
```

Comment: This is not MySql code. Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry, its SQL Server

Comment: Please edit the question to change the tag `mysql` -> `sql-server`.

Comment: *"the actual format of Triage Start time is - 01-JAN-2000 23:22"* Date and time data types don't have a "format", they are binary values. The displayed format is determined by the presentation layer, not the database. If you just want the time portion of a date and time value, then just convert it to a `time`. Example `CONVERT(time(0),GETDATE())`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I also suspect that if you only care about one column then you can significantly simplify the query in the question.